# match 2 column elements based on a differece within a range

Tags: r

I want to match the elements of two unequal columns from two different data frames if they fall within the range: 1 to 3 (2+/-1)

My data frames:

dat1:

```
Number  status
10023   T
10324   F
12277   F
12888   T
12000   T
```

dat2:

```
Number  status
10020   T
10002   F
12279   F
12888   T
```

Required ouput:

```
10023   10020   T
12277   12279   F
```

My attempt (below) did not work:

```
diff <- 2
allow <- 1

NewData <- dat1$Number %in% (dat2$Number<=diff+allow | dat2$Number>=diff+allow)
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you matching 12888 too, its an exact match?

Comment: Thanks guys - now edited

Comment: Do you want to match by same status too or just ranges?

Comment: I want to match both ranges and status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a must case for `data.table::foverlaps` to me.

The workflow is to create `start` and `end` columns within both data sets, while we will create the range within the second data set. Then, we will `key` both and simply run `foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)
diff <- 2
allow <- 1
setDT(dat1)[, `:=`(start = Number, end = Number)]
setkey(dat1, status, start, end)
setDT(dat2)[, `:=`(start = Number - (diff + allow), end = Number + diff + allow)]
setkey(dat2, status, start, end)
foverlaps(dat2, dat1, nomatch = 0L)[, .(Numdf1 = Number, Numdf2 = i.Number, status)]

#    Numdf1 Numdf2 status
# 1:  12277  12279  FALSE
# 2:  10023  10020   TRUE
# 3:  12888  12888   TRUE ### <- I'm assuming you had an error in the desirred output
```

Comment: Nice solution. Not only fast, but also able to handle multiple matches.

Comment: Really nice solution - I agree with Pierre. David and Pierre, thanks so much to both of you. David's code worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: On question  to David: what if I just want to match just by ranges and not including status how would the code be different?

Comment: Just remove `status` from both keys. e.g. `setkey(dat1, start, end)` and `setkey(dat2, start, end)` and then run `foverlaps` as before.

Comment: @user27976 see my comment above, I wasn't aware that you were the one whos asking.

Comment: Thanks once again David